# Extrude modifier causing hollow shapes

Tags: extrude

Every time I try to extrude a face on a plane it has created this hollow shape. I don't think this used to happen and its happening on all my files. How do I fix this? I want a solid to be formed from extruding. I know I can fill the faces but I'm not sure if its an issue with my settings that is causing this?

[image]

Comment: I have tried recalculating normals but that hasn't fixed it :(

Comment: because the other face needs thickness as well, extrude both, then extrude only the left one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extrude a face, it won't keep the initial face:

[image]

Unless you extrude or all the adjacent faces as well (or unless you extrude a mesh with one unique face):

[image]

If your object has already thickness, as you can see it won't keep the initial face either, otherwise you would need to delete it every time you extrude:

[image]